# What is the way to use free maps in android studio project?

Tags: android, maps

I have a need to show maps in android studio application and the map should be free.
I have searched on the web but i am not sure: could you recommend the free map for android application and the way of using it?

Thank you

Comment: you can use google map but it has some limit

Comment: @kam1234 as i understand you mean mapView right? is it free? because as i know it requires apikey.

Comment: yup apikey is free for some request

Comment: you can use it in production process

Comment: They will ask for your credit card. But unless you get a high number of requests they won't charge anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Open Street maps](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid). it's free alternative of Google Maps SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Well google maps sdk offer a good free limit tier of 100,000 map loads per month, also there is a $200 monthly credit for Maps Platform usage in google cloud. I dont think you can exceed this limit for a small project, If you exceeded then you can sure afford paying the extra credit.
You can generate a free api key to get your maps working, I dont think other maps option can be reliable as google maps

Other options are still available:

- [OpenStreetMaps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/)
- [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/)
- [HERE maps](https://www.here.com/)
- [Bing Maps](https://www.bing.com/maps)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use Google Maps SDK, totally free but with request limit for some features, Sign for you api key and connect it with you android app and keep going

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro

Comment: 'totally free'?? Nonsense, it's literally the most expensive maps api there is on the market